# Passing JSON via Query Parameters from URL (Cross Domain)

Tags: jquery, json, url, cross-domain

I came across a problem to transmit JSON over JS applications (Cross Domain), to use classic query parameter is kind of overkill, if you have list or list within a list of your original JSON, it will be over complicated to deal with.....

If the JSON is not TOO big, if it is under the limitation of an URL can contains, we could use a different way to do this.....(Please see answer of my post)

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the JSON into URL safe string:

   `var myJsonStr= JSON.stringify(myJson);
   var myJsonURLSafe= encodeURIComponent(myJsonStr);`
2. Passing it on your target URL with a SINGLE parameter:

   `window.location.replace(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/mysite/#targetPage?myJson='+myJsonURLSafe);`
3. On the other side of transmission, after we read this parameter, we convert it back to JSON:

   ```
   //function to read parameters
    getUrlVars: function () {
                   var vars = [], hash;
                   var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                   for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                       hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                       vars.push(hash[0]);
                       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                   }
                   return vars;
               }
   ```

function to get the JSON:

```
     getMyJsonData:function(){
         var urlValue = this.getUrlVars()["myJson"];
         var dataJSON = undefined;
         if(urlValue){
             var dataStr= decodeURIComponent(urlValue);
             dataJSON = JSON.parse(dataStr);
         }
    return dataJSON;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, i was editing my code, it should be dataJSON which i did JSON.parse from the dataStr, give a min

Comment: there's also a `location.search` property that you can both get and set and manipulating a url in `document.createElement('a')` exposes all those properties also